# Libreoffice in-text citation numbering

Tags: libreoffice

I am writing a paper that has in-text citations spread throughout that are just sequential numbers. Is there a way to do this so that if I add something in the middle, I don't have to go and manually renumber all of them?

Comment: Please add details how the "citations" should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into using a dedicated citation manager like [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org) or [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/). Plugins for LibreOffice and other word processors are available:

- https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_installation
- http://resources.mendeley.com/Mendeley_Desktop/write_cite/

Both plugins update reference numbers and bibliography entries whenever you insert a new citation.